# Wamp server error message: Undefined variable: _post?

Tags: php, mysql, post

I am trying to link a HTML form to a mySQL database using a wamp server, the server connects to the database perfectly however it wont let me post my form data due to a error message Undefined variable: _post can somebody help solve whats going wrong below is my PHP code.

```
<?php
define ('DB_NAME', 'feedback');
define ('DB_USER', 'root');
define ('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link){
die('could not connect' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if(!$db_selected){
die('cant use' . DB_NAME . ':' . mysql_error());
}

$_value = $_post['name'];
$_value1 = $_post['feedback'];

 $sqlname = "INSERT INTO feedback (name) VALUES ('$_value')";

 if (!mysql_query($sqlname)){
die('error:' . mysql_error());
 }

 $sqlfeedback = "INSERT INTO feedback (feedback) VALUES ('$value1')";

 if (!mysql_query($sqlfeedback)){
die('error:' . mysql_error());
 }<?php */

 mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: It's `$_POST` not `$_post`. cAsE maTTerS.

Comment: `<form action="post">` but `$_POST` - I can understand the confusion.

Comment: Thank you very much your both life savers solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Variables are case sensitive in php, so it should be `$_POST['name']`and not`$_post['name']`.

Keep in mind tho, fonctions aren't case sensitive.